# ¿Cómo mezclar streams de audio con ffmpeg?

Tags: ffmpeg

No he logrado concatenar dos pistas de audio con diferentes formatos (una es .mp3 y la otra .oga) y diferentes volumenes. Intenté varias combinaciones de comandos con ffmpeg pero siempre el resultado ha sido que una de las pistas de audio sobre escribe la anterior o queda en blanco (no se escucha nada pero es la duración completa de ambas pistas) o "ruido blanco"

Comment: Muestra que has intentado, para poder ayudarte mejor.

Answer (score 0):

Mezclando los audios, reduciendo el volumen de la música, en **output_merge.mp3**:

```
ffmpeg -hide_banner -loglevel quiet -i "musica.mp3" -filter:a "volume=0.3" -y "music.mp3" && ffmpeg -hide_banner -loglevel quiet -i "music.mp3" -i "voice.oga" -filter_complex amix=inputs=2:duration=longest -y "output_merge.mp3"
```

El archivo de salida **output_merge.mp3** lo puedes dejar en el formato que quieras, ffmpeg es bastante flexible en cuanto a formatos en general.